# why does using the inverse give the same answer of this integral.

Tags: integration

Find the area bounded by $x=4-y^2$ and $x=y-2$

$A = \int_{-5}^0 \left[\left(x+2\right) + \sqrt{4-x}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^4 2\sqrt{4-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

This is the solution in the book.

How I solved it.  The first time I used the inverses and got the correct answer.

$\int_{-2}^1 \left(-x^2+4-x-2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Can I do this for any problem. When asked to integrate on the $y$-axis, just take the inverse and integrate on the $x$-axis?

Comment: be careful for getting the x values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are taking the inverse of a function you are basically getting a mirror image of the function about $y=x$ line .

I personally find this as a very good method . Suppose you want to integrate $\ln(x)$ from $x = 0$ to $x=1$ , what i used to do was take the inverse of the function (which in this case is $e^x$)  and then integrate from $x = -\infty$ to $x=0$ , because integrating $e^x $ compared to $\ln(x)$ is easy , otherwise you will need by parts to integrate .

So , sometimes it is advantageous to integrate the inverse of the function , but BE CAREFUL to select the right $x$ values , otherwise you will get the wrong answer .